# Practical way to check for geometric convergence

Tags: markov-chains, integration, st.statistics, ergodic-theory, pr.probability

Target distribution is multimodal, 24 dimensions, continuous state space. For MCMC integration (MH sampler) I use a manually tuned proposal distribution.

When I measure the convergence rate numerically I observe only a *polynomial* convergence rate.

I have a complete freedom of choice for the proposal distribution. Are there practically useful conditions to quickly check if a particular proposal distribution leads to the *geometric* convergence rate?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is a difficult topic. Maybe this recent manuscript could be helpful

- [Johnson and Geyer (2012). Variable Transformation to Obtain Geometric Ergodicity in the Random-walk Metropolis Algorithm.](http://www.stat.umn.edu/geyer/morph/VariableTransformation.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. An interesting reading indeed.
The only question I have is that it seems like the transformation can help with heavy tails. However it is not clear for me how it helps with reachability of distinct modes.

Thanks,
Anton

Comment: @Anton. That is definitely an interesting (and not easy) question. It is not clear to me either.